# Capture fn keycode on air window

Tags: actionscript-3, air

On laptop, I want to capture the fn-key on the Mac keyboard in my CMS application. 
But when I press fn key, no keycode found.

Could you help me to solve that?

Comment: Actually that's quite simple: **you can't**

Answer (score 0):

Some key aren't sent to Flash Player.

If neither `KEY_UP` nor `KEY_DOWN` are fired, then you simply can't catch that key.